# Error in Cocoa pod file 'XLPagerTabStrip' in Xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode10, swift4.2, xlpagertabstrip

My Xcode version is 10.0 and Swift 4.2.

When I update my pod file, I am seeing the error as shown in the screenshot.
[image]

I think 'XLPagerTabStrip' pod file is not getting updated to latest release. To verify this, I created a sample project and installed 'XLPagerTabStrip' pod file only. There also I can see the same error.

Comment: click to fixed.

Comment: We should not modify anything directly in the pod file. And also pod files are locked.

Comment: unlock pod file

Comment: It's not a good process to unlock pod file and modify directly.

Comment: not possible to this error solution.

Answer (score 0):

try following pod command ==>

pod deintegrate

and after this try following command ==>

pod install

it will take a while but definitely solve the problem.